# Preferences Fragment not working in PageViewer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been looking around and I cant really find any good answers that solve my problem.

I'm currently using a Page Viewer to view a bunch of fragments. I now want one of the fragments to be a preferences page, which would be easiest done with a preferences fragment. However in my adapter when i am directing which page is which fragment i get the error:

Incompatible types.

Required:
android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Found:
package...Settings_Fragment

Is there any way to get a v4 support preferences fragment. I really don't want to have to rebuild my app with non-v4 fragments.

Is there any way i can solve this?

Thanks in advance, sorry if its a silly question!

Answer (score 0):

Yup - just use [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html).